# Is it possible to have enumerated data types in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to have enumerated data types in NetLogo?

Let's say that I have a model of marital status change.

An agent can have 3 marital status states: single, married, divorced.

I would like to map those states into numbers so that it takes less memory when executed.

- single = 1
- married = 2
- divorced = 3

so that I can just do

```
ask agents with [ marital-status = single ][ get-married ]
```

I have found a trick to do that with "to-report"

eg:

```
to-report single
   report 1
end
```

But this means I have to create many to report functions if I were to have many categories in many variables. Is there a better workaround than this?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is an excellent question! I normally just use strings for this. They are more readable in code than numbers are. The assumption that strings use more memory than numbers isn't correct. If I have 1000 turtles and I say `ask turtles [ set marital-status "single" ]`, all 1000 turtles store a reference to the same string, I don't end up with 1000 copies of the string.

Comment: Hi @SethTisue, thank you for the clarification on my misunderstanding. I actually have a follow up question from this but not sure if I should put it on a new thread (let me know if I need to). Does `import-world` perform slower when some variables were stored as strings?

Comment: @SethTisue Good to know. I always use strings as well for readability, but I hadn't realised I had a good reason for not caring about the memory implications :)

Comment: @z5182 please open a new question on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your model? My understanding is that an agent attribute is minimum 8 bytes anyway (see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Optimizing-NetLogo-Runs)

I can't think of a natural way to do this. However, if you really wanted to, this workaround would work: store the marital status as 0, 1, 2. Also store a global variable called marriage-status-map and use the `item` primitive. So it would look like this:

```
globals [ marriage-status-map]

turtles-own [ marriage-status ]

to testme
  clear-all
  set marriage-status-map ["single" "married" "divorced"]
  create-turtles 10
  [ set marriage-status random 3
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
  ]
  ask turtles with [item marriage-status marriage-status-map = "single"] [set color red]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JenB. This is certainly an option for me to consider. However, I should also test for the difference in runtime of the two methods (using to-report and yours). My model is quite large with 2GB+ in RAM usage (200k+ agents).

Comment: @z5182 You didn't mention it so I just wanted to check that you are aware of the profiler extension that makes runtime checks straightforward.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion of profiler I will check it out.